# How to do iterations in R?

Tags: r, loops, iteration

I'm operating with a dataset that contains the values of same variables at different points in time. In the example below I have the values of variables a and b at time points 1 and 2.

```
> set.seed(1)
> data <- data.frame(matrix(sample(16), ncol = 4))
> names(data) <- paste(rep(c("a", "b"), each = 2), 1:2, sep = "")
> data
  a1 a2 b1 b2
1  5  3 14 13
2  6 10  1  8
3  9 11  2  4
4 12 15  7 16
```

Now, suppose I want to calculate a new variable for both time points so that it would contain the sum of a and b (instead of the NAs as in example below). Since my actual dataset contains about 15 different variables and 10 time points (so 150 columns), I want to automate this calculation of 10 new variables.

```
> data[, paste("ab", 1:2, sep = "")] <- NA
> data
  a1 a2 b1 b2 ab1 ab2
1  5  3 14 13  NA  NA
2  6 10  1  8  NA  NA
3  9 11  2  4  NA  NA
4 12 15  7 16  NA  NA
```

I've previously used Stata where I could create a simple 'foreach' loop to do this. Something like below.

```
foreach t of numlist 1/2 {
    generate ab`t' = a`t' + b`t'
}
```

But I've learned that using loops in R is not feasible, nor have I any idea how to loop over variable names like that in R.

So what would be the correct solution for my problem in R?

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432686/r-how-to-sum-pairs-in-a-matrix-by-row

Comment: You could also consider turning your data to long format. Like this, it's not tidy data as you have information in the column names.

Comment: @Heroka I actually reshaped the data to wide format as it seemed more simple to operate on. But you're correct in this not being tidy, so I might rethink that.

Comment: your issue/question seems less about iteration than about Stata's compact syntax to paste variables into names in a loop. (That is, `for(i in 1:2) {}` accomplishes the same loop in R

Comment: @jaimedash My Stata solution was only an example. Since according to the "Internet" loops are not recommended in R I was actually looking for a solution that would not involve looping but other ways of iteration (e.g. using apply and/or functions).

Comment: ok, I think you should rephrase the question. this isn't really a situation where you need to avoid loops but I understand your interest in the 'idiomatic' R way. I'd say @Sotos answer is closest to that

Comment: but I added another that uses more convenient features of R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to do this the `R` way,

1. make use of some native iteration via a `*apply` function
2. use the built-in `rowSums` (as in @Sotos) answer
3. make use of assignment into the data.frame, that is `]`<-

all together

```
data[paste0('ab', 1:2)] <- sapply(1:2,
                                  function(i)
                                     rowSums(data[paste0(c('a', 'b'), i)]))
data

#   a1 a2 b1 b2 ab1 ab2
# 1  5  3 14 13  19  16
# 2  6 10  1  8   7  18
# 3  9 11  2  4  11  15
# 4 12 15  7 16  19  31
```

ps, in a program use `vapply` instead, you'll need to provide an additional argument specifying the shape of the output but its safer and sometimes faster

Answer (score 3):

This will replicate the same foreach loop you used in Stata.

```
for(i in 1:2){
  data[, paste("ab", i, sep="")] <- 
    data[,paste("a", i, sep="")] + data[, paste("b", i, sep="")]
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
> data
  a1 a2 b1 b2 ab1 ab2
1 15  1 16 12  31  13
2 10  7 14  3  24  10
3  2  5  9  4  11   9
4  6  8 13 11  19  19
```

Comment: I tried a loop, but could not figure out how to refer to columns using a loop variable like that. Thanks!

Comment: you can do `paste0(...)` instead of `paste( ..., sep="")`

Answer (score 2):

You can do without iteration:

```
data$ab1 <- data$a1 + data$b1
data$ab2 <- data$a2 + data$b2
```

or

```
data <- transform(data, ab1=a1+b1, ab2=a2+b2)
```

BTW:
It is better not to name an object `data` because `data=` is often a parameter in functions.

Comment: I know I can do without iteration but was explicitly looking for a more sophisticated solution (and learn something while at it). As mentioned, my original dataset has values for about 15 variables at 10 points in time, so my R code would become quite messy if I simply typed in every single calculation.

Comment: ok, for a more complex situation I gave the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432686/r-how-to-sum-pairs-in-a-matrix-by-row The other hint was given by Heroka: reshaping to long format. (or in your case: not shaping to the wide format.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it. We iterate over the unique values of the column names and we calculate the `rowSums` when those unique values match the colname values.

```
sapply(unique(sub('\\D', '', names(data))), 
             function(i) rowSums(data[,grepl(i, sub('\\D', '', names(data)))]))
#      1  2
#[1,] 17 23
#[2,] 24 22
#[3,] 14 10
#[4,] 15 11
```